# Web deployment task failed for ASP.NET MVC static website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

Trying to deploy a simple ASP.NET MVC web application (static website) in Azure, but getting this error:

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://evlife.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=EVLife'.)
> Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://evlife.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=EVLife'.
> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Same as a screenshot:

[image]

Browsed many articles but getting generic solution not an expected.

My stacks are: VS2013, ASP.NET MVC web application (static website), Azure Free subscription.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- We have tried to Publish the Sample `ASP.Net MVC` using `Import Profile` , got the same error which you have mentioned.
- If we skip the Validating Connection step and continue to publish, got the below error

[image]

- Able to publish the App using `VS 2017`  without any issues
  [image]
- I have found docs related to Publishing App to Azure using VS [2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-azure?view=vs-2022),[2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-azure?view=vs-2019) and [2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/azure/vs-azure-tools-publish-azure-application-wizard?view=vs-2015) but not for VS 2013.
- We suggest you use the latest version of VS and publish the Web App.